# Spring Security plugin displaying wrong labels in views

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm having a problem with the Spring Security plugin views, the labels are not correct, as it is shown in the following image:

[image: Wrong labels]

I have just followed the basic steps:
- Install plugin with

```
grails install-plugin spring-security-core
```

- Run

  grails s2-quickstart org.example SecUser SecRole
- Add the following to UrlMappings.groovy:

  "/login/$action?"(controller: "login")
  "/logout/$action?"(controller: "logout")
- Run my app (Liquidaciones).
- Go to .../Liquidaciones/login/auth

Why is this happening? I have used this plugin before (a previous version) and I didn't have this problem.

I'm using:
- Grails 2.2.2
- Spring Security Core 1.2.7.3
- IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 12.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is working correctly! I didn't tell you my OS is Windows 7. This is what I did:

1. Uncompress Grails 2.2.3 in my C directory.
2. Edit the GRAILS_HOME variable changing it to
   `GRAILS_HOME=C:\grails-2.2.3\`
3. Edit application.properties file, changing Grails version from 2.2.2
   to 2.2.3, like this: `app.grails.version=2.2.3`
4. Right click in the Liquidaciones (this is my project name) node, select
   `Grails`, select `Change SDK version`, add and select the Grails
   2.2.3 distribution.

After doing this I have my Grails app secured with Spring Security displaying the right labels.

Thanks Burt Beckwith!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include your image, but I'm assuming you're seeing http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10058 which is fixed in Grails 2.2.3

Comment: I see. But how can I fix it? I have just to write manually the correct labels? Or do I have to reconfigure my project to point to a new (2.2.3) Grails installation folder? Give a clue please, I'm a Grails beginner.

Comment: Upgrade to 2.2.3. Don't run `grails upgrade` since it's just a small jump - install 2.2.3 the same way you did earlier (http://gvmtool.net/ is the best way btw) and edit `application.properties`, changing 2.2.2 to 2.2.3

Comment: Now it is working correctly! I didn't tell you my OS is Windows 7. This is what I did: 1. Uncompressed